# 2 analog sensors, pulse sensor and LM35 problem

Tags: sensors, temperature

I make a project in which I use two analog sensors. A pulse sensor and the LM35 temperature sensor. When I use them separated everything is normal,the codes are fine, when I combine them the lm35 is not precise, has an error margin of about 10 degrees but the pulse sensor seems to be ok. I read something about the analog to digital convertor that Arduino have and need a delay or something to trick the ADC. 
I would be grateful if somebody help me to modify the code. 
Thank you very much!

```cpp
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <TonePlayer.h>

const int rs = 12, en = 11, d4 = 5, d5 = 4, d6 = 3, d7 = 2;
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

int pulsePin = A0;                 // Pulse Sensor purple wire connected to analog pin A0
int blinkPin = 13;                // pin to blink led at each beat

const int sensor=A5; // Assigning analog pin A5 to variable ‘sensor’ temperature
float tempc;
float vout; //temporary variable to hold sensor reading

TonePlayer tone1 (TCCR1A, TCCR1B, OCR1AH, OCR1AL, TCNT1H, TCNT1L);  // pin D9 (Uno), D11 (Mega)

// Volatile Variables, used in the interrupt service routine!
volatile int BPM;                   // int that holds raw Analog in 0. updated every 2mS
volatile int Signal;                // holds the incoming raw data
volatile int IBI = 600;             // int that holds the time interval between beats! Must be seeded! 
volatile boolean Pulse = false;     // "True" when User's live heartbeat is detected. "False" when not a "live beat". 
volatile boolean QS = false;        // becomes true when Arduoino finds a beat.

static boolean serialVisual = true;   // Set to 'false' by Default.  Re-set to 'true' to see Arduino Serial Monitor ASCII Visual Pulse 

volatile int rate[10];                      // array to hold last ten IBI values
volatile unsigned long sampleCounter = 0;          // used to determine pulse timing
volatile unsigned long lastBeatTime = 0;           // used to find IBI
volatile int P = 512;                      // used to find peak in pulse wave, seeded
volatile int T = 512;                     // used to find trough in pulse wave, seeded
volatile int thresh = 525;                // used to find instant moment of heart beat, seeded
volatile int amp = 100;                   // used to hold amplitude of pulse waveform, seeded
volatile boolean firstBeat = true;        // used to seed rate array so we startup with reasonable BPM
volatile boolean secondBeat = false;      // used to seed rate array so we startup with reasonable BPM


void setup() {

  pinMode(blinkPin,OUTPUT);         // pin that will blink to your heartbeat!
  pinMode (9, OUTPUT);  // output pin is fixed (OC1A)

  Serial.begin(115200);             // we agree to talk fast!
  interruptSetup();                 // sets up to read Pulse Sensor signal every 2mS 
                                    // IF YOU ARE POWERING The Pulse Sensor AT VOLTAGE LESS THAN THE BOARD VOLTAGE, 
                                    // UN-COMMENT THE NEXT LINE AND APPLY THAT VOLTAGE TO THE A-REF PIN

  pinMode(sensor,INPUT); // Configuring pin A1 as input                             //   analogReference(EXTERNAL);   

  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.clear();
}


//  Where the Magic Happens
void loop() {
  serialOutput();  
  if (QS == true) { // A Heartbeat Was Found
    // BPM and IBI have been Determined
    // Quantified Self "QS" true when arduino finds a heartbeat
    serialOutputWhenBeatHappens(); // A Beat Happened, Output that to serial.     
    QS = false; // reset the Quantified Self flag for next time  

    vout=analogRead(sensor);
    vout=(vout*500)/1023;
    tempc=vout; // Storing value in Degree Celsius

    Serial.print ("Temperatura: ");
    Serial.print(tempc);
    Serial.println(" C ");

  }
  delay(20); //  take a break
}


void interruptSetup() {     
  // Initializes Timer2 to throw an interrupt every 2mS.
  TCCR2A = 0x02;     // DISABLE PWM ON DIGITAL PINS 3 AND 11, AND GO INTO CTC MODE
  TCCR2B = 0x06;     // DON'T FORCE COMPARE, 256 PRESCALER 
  OCR2A = 0X7C;      // SET THE TOP OF THE COUNT TO 124 FOR 500Hz SAMPLE RATE
  TIMSK2 = 0x02;     // ENABLE INTERRUPT ON MATCH BETWEEN TIMER2 AND OCR2A
  sei();             // MAKE SURE GLOBAL INTERRUPTS ARE ENABLED      
} 

void serialOutput() {   // Decide How To Output Serial. 
 if (serialVisual == true){  
     arduinoSerialMonitorVisual('-', Signal);   // goes to function that makes Serial Monitor Visualizer
  } else{
      sendDataToSerial('S', Signal);     // goes to sendDataToSerial function
   }        
}

void serialOutputWhenBeatHappens() {    
 if (serialVisual == true) { //  Code to Make the Serial Monitor Visualizer Work

     Serial.print("Batai ");  //ASCII Art Madness
     Serial.print("BPM: ");
     Serial.println(BPM);
     lcd.print("Batai ");
     lcd.setCursor(6,0);
     lcd.print("BPM: ");
     lcd.setCursor(10,0);
     lcd.print(BPM);


     lcd.setCursor(0,1);
     lcd.print("Temp: ");
     lcd.setCursor(6,1);
     lcd.print(tempc);
     lcd.setCursor(11,1);
     lcd.print("C ");

     delay(300);
     lcd.clear();
   } else {
     sendDataToSerial('B',BPM);   // send heart rate with a 'B' prefix
     sendDataToSerial('Q',IBI);   // send time between beats with a 'Q' prefix
   }   
}

void arduinoSerialMonitorVisual(char symbol, int data ) {    
  const int sensorMin = 0;      // sensor minimum, discovered through experiment
  const int sensorMax = 1024;    // sensor maximum, discovered through experiment
  int sensorReading = data; // map the sensor range to a range of 12 options:
  int range = map(sensorReading, sensorMin, sensorMax, 0, 11);
  // do something different depending on the 
  // range value:
}


void sendDataToSerial(char symbol, int data ) {
   Serial.print(symbol);
   Serial.println(data);                
}

ISR(TIMER2_COMPA_vect) { //triggered when Timer2 counts to 124

  cli();                                      // disable interrupts while we do this
  Signal = analogRead(pulsePin);              // read the Pulse Sensor 
  sampleCounter += 2;                         // keep track of the time in mS with this variable
  int N = sampleCounter - lastBeatTime;       // monitor the time since the last beat to avoid noise
                                              //  find the peak and trough of the pulse wave
  if(Signal < thresh && N > (IBI/5)*3) { // avoid dichrotic noise by waiting 3/5 of last IBI 
    if (Signal < T) { // T is the trough                     
      T = Signal; // keep track of lowest point in pulse wave 
    }
  }

  if(Signal > thresh && Signal > P) {       // thresh condition helps avoid noise
    P = Signal;                             // P is the peak
  }                                        // keep track of highest point in pulse wave

  //  NOW IT'S TIME TO LOOK FOR THE HEART BEAT
  // signal surges up in value every time there is a pulse
  if (N > 250) {                                   // avoid high frequency noise
    if ( (Signal > thresh) && (Pulse == false) && (N > (IBI/5)*3) ) {        
        Pulse = true;                               // set the Pulse flag when we think there is a pulse
        digitalWrite(blinkPin,HIGH);                // turn on pin 13 LED
        tone1.tone (1000);  // 1000 Hz

        IBI = sampleCounter - lastBeatTime;         // measure time between beats in mS
        lastBeatTime = sampleCounter;               // keep track of time for next pulse

        if(secondBeat) {                        // if this is the second beat, if secondBeat == TRUE
          secondBeat = false;                   // clear secondBeat flag
          for(int i=0; i<=9; i++) { // seed the running total to get a realisitic BPM at startup
            rate[i] = IBI;                      
          }
        }

        if(firstBeat) { // if it's the first time we found a beat, if firstBeat == TRUE                
          firstBeat = false;                   // clear firstBeat flag
          secondBeat = true;                   // set the second beat flag
          sei();                               // enable interrupts again
          return;                              // IBI value is unreliable so discard it
        }   
      // keep a running total of the last 10 IBI values
      word runningTotal = 0;                    // clear the runningTotal variable    

      for(int i=0; i<=8; i++) {                 // shift data in the rate array
          rate[i] = rate[i+1];                  // and drop the oldest IBI value 
          runningTotal += rate[i];              // add up the 9 oldest IBI values
        }

      rate[9] = IBI;                          // add the latest IBI to the rate array
      runningTotal += rate[9];                // add the latest IBI to runningTotal
      runningTotal /= 10;                     // average the last 10 IBI values 
      BPM = 60000/runningTotal;               // how many beats can fit into a minute? that's BPM!
      QS = true;                              // set Quantified Self flag 
      // QS FLAG IS NOT CLEARED INSIDE THIS ISR
    }                       
  }

  if (Signal < thresh && Pulse == true) {    // when the values are going down, the beat is over
      digitalWrite(blinkPin,LOW);            // turn off pin 13 LED
      tone1.noTone ();
      Pulse = false;                         // reset the Pulse flag so we can do it again
      amp = P - T;                           // get amplitude of the pulse wave
      thresh = amp/2 + T;                    // set thresh at 50% of the amplitude
      P = thresh;                            // reset these for next time
      T = thresh;
    }

  if (N > 2500) {                          // if 2.5 seconds go by without a beat
    thresh = 512;                          // set thresh default
    P = 512;                               // set P default
    T = 512;                               // set T default
    lastBeatTime = sampleCounter;          // bring the lastBeatTime up to date        
    firstBeat = true;                      // set these to avoid noise
    secondBeat = false;                    // when we get the heartbeat back
  }
  sei();                                   // enable interrupts when youre done!
}// end isr
```

Comment: When you use the sensors separately, are you still using this code you've posted? If not, how is the separate code - especially for the LM35 - different from the above?

Comment: I still use this code, my problem is that i don't know how to combine them correctly. the code only for LM35 is the next one. ` const int sensor=A5; 
float tempc; 
float vout;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);          

}

void loop() {
    vout=analogRead(sensor);
    vout=(vout*500)/1023;
    tempc=vout; // Storing value in Degree Celsius

    Serial.print ("Temperatura: ");
    Serial.print(tempc);
    Serial.println(" C ");
    delay(1000);
} `

Answer (score 2):

I have a couple of suggestions:

The combined code is very different from the simple LM35 code that works. I'd suggest you start with the combined code but comment out everything that doesn't directly apply to reading the LM35, and get that working correctly.

The interrupt service routine (ISR) is trying to do too much, and leaves the interrupts off during all of those calculation. Plus, its hard to debug code inside an ISR! ISRs should do the *minimum work that they have to do*. In this case, it looks like it needs to read & save the pulse sensor value and do the `N`, `lastBeatTime`, and `sampleCounter` calculation. Have it also set a flag every time it runs.

The main loop should check that flag, and if it is set, clear it and call another function to do everything you took out of the ISR. Debug this code, perhaps with the LM35 commented out.

Ideally your `loop()` function should be as simple as:

```
void loop(){
   Timers.run();
   maybeCalcHeartbeat();
   maybeDoOtherSubtask();
   ...
}
```

Then the rest of your code goes into "maybeDo" functions. A "maybeDo" just decides whether the time or conditions are right to do a particular thing; if so, the function does it; but in any case, it returns quickly:

```
void maybeCalcHeartbeat(void){
   if( !isrFlag )
      return;
   else {
      // everything you took out of the ISR goes here //

      isrFlag = false;
   }
```